# How to compare data in a table with the current year and immediate past year

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in MySQL table, I am trying to compare those data by the current year value and the immediate past year.

```
Books
|   id  |   Name    |
|   01  |   Maths   |
|   02  |   English |   

BooksTable
| Books |   value   |   Year    |
| 01    |   40      |   2012    |
| 02    |   30      |   2012    |
| 02    |   50      |   2013    |
| 01    |   50      |   2013    |
| 01    |   60      |   2014    |
```

I want an optimized and better way to compare the books value by the year (2013 and 2014), and be able to output it into an html table via php.
This is how I would want it to appear in the HTML table

```
HTML TABLE
| BOOKS  |  2013    |   2014    |
| Maths  |   50     |   60      |
| English|   50     |   -       |
```

This is what I did:

1. I first queried data for only 2013
2. and then queried data for only 2014
3. I made the comparison in the 2014 while statement

The errors I had
1. All the queries runs null if the 2014 query returns empty, since the output for 2013 query was dependent on 2014 query

**UPDATE**
Please this is what i tried

```
//query for the year 2013
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.books,
    b.value
FROM
    BOOKS a
JOIN
    BooksTable b
ON
    a.id=b.books
WHERE
    year=2013


//query for the year 2014
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.books,
    b.value
FROM
    BOOKS a
JOIN
    BooksTable b
ON
    a.id=b.books
WHERE
    year=2014
```

Please, I know I am doing the wrong thing, is there an optimized and better way to this? I would be grateful if someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: what u tried so far ?

Comment: And you have only 3 years ?

Comment: The years could be more, but for better understanding i used only 3 years

Comment: Maybe use COALESCE(value_for_2014, 0) somewhere in the Query for 2014, so you are not calculating with NULL values.

Comment: WHere are your queries? and why is 2013 query depending on 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own way, this is how I will solve it with php and mysql

```
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        b.books,
        IFNULL(NULL,'0') AS  currentValue,
        IFNULL(b.value,0) as PastValue
    FROM
        `Books` a
    JOIN
        `BooksTable` b
    ON
        a.id=b.id
             and
        Year='2013'

UNION ALL

    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        b.books,
        IFNULL(b.value,0) as currentValue,
        IFNULL(NULL,0) as PastValue  

    FROM
        `Books` a
    JOIN
        `BooksTable` b
    ON
        a.id=b.id
            and
        Year='2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
SELECT b.Name, IFNULL(bt1.value, '-') as PastYear, IFNULL(bt2.value, '-') as CurrentYear
FROM Books b
LEFT JOIN BooksTable bt1 ON b.id=bt1.Books AND bt1.Year = (SELECT bt1y.Year FROM BooksTable bt1y GROUP BY bt1y.Year ORDER BY bt1y.Year DESC LIMIT 1,1)
LEFT JOIN BooksTable bt2 ON b.id=bt2.Books AND bt2.Year = (SELECT bt2y.Year FROM BooksTable bt2y GROUP BY bt2y.Year ORDER BY bt2y.Year DESC LIMIT 0,1)
```

That will return the data in the same way you want to show it in html, so just loop it once:

[image: output]

Comment: The years could be more like 2015 and 2014, it  shouldnt be only the 2013 and 2014. I used that to best clarify what i wanted.

Comment: @George Okey then, no need to downvote, I just said IF that was the case. Anyway, you always want the last two years, or all the years?

Comment: @George check it out now.

Comment: Yeah, that works somewhat, but assuming you want to select some specific years. Wld it be possible?

Comment: If you want to select specific years just replace the nested SELECTS for the desired years.

Comment: To my way of thinking, this is a poor solution.

Comment: @Strawberry why is that? It should be faster than your proposal... and fits in 4 lines.

Comment: @Pinx0 I'll try to set out my reasons in due course, but performance wasn't particularly one of them. That said, if you think your solution's faster than mine, I'd be interested to see you prove it!

Comment: @Pinx0, when i use the year in place of the nested SELECTS it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I would just execute the simplest query possible, and handle the display issues in PHP (not shown).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Books;

CREATE TABLE books
(book_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Name    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO books VALUES
(01  ,'Maths'),
(02  ,'English');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book_values;

CREATE TABLE book_values
(book_id INT NOT NULL 
,value   INT NOT NULL
,Year    INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(book_id,year)
);

INSERT INTO book_values
VALUES
(01    ,40      ,2012    ),
(02    ,30      ,2012    ),
(02    ,50      ,2013    ),
(01    ,50      ,2013    ),
(01    ,60      ,2014    );

SELECT b.*,v.value,v.year FROM books b JOIN book_values v ON v.book_id = b.book_id WHERE v.year IN (2013,2014);
+---------+---------+-------+------+
| book_id | Name    | value | year |
+---------+---------+-------+------+
|       1 | Maths   |    50 | 2013 |
|       1 | Maths   |    60 | 2014 |
|       2 | English |    50 | 2013 |
+---------+---------+-------+------+
```

EDIT: I'm not too great at PHP or manipulating arrays within it, but something like this...

```
<?php

include('path/to/connection/statem.ent');

$query = "
SELECT b.*
     , v.value
     , v.year
  FROM books b
  JOIN book_values v
    ON v.book_id = b.book_id
 WHERE v.year IN (2013,2014)
 ORDER
    BY b.book_id
     , v.year;";

$old_array = array();

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$old_array[] = $row;
}

$new_array = Array();

foreach( $old_array as $v )
{
    if(!isset( $new_array[$v["Name"]][$v["year"]] ))
    {
        $new_array[$v["Name"]][$v["year"]] = 0;
    }
    $new_array[$v["Name"]][$v["year"]] += $v["value"];
}
print_r($new_array);

?>
```

... will produce an array like this...

```
Array
(
    [Maths] => Array
        (
            [2013] => 50
            [2014] => 60
        )

    [English] => Array
        (
            [2013] => 50
        )

)
```

Hopefully, you can figure out how to spit that out to an html table.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not have function to generate the pivot tables i.e. showing the row value as column. You can do it using dynamic sql query with prepared statement.

There are plenty of tutorials on it (mysql showing row data as column.) 
In your case the following should do the job.

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'sum(case when bt.Year = ''',
      Year,
      ''' THEN bt.value ELSE 0 END) AS ',
      CONCAT('`',Year, '`')
    )
  ) into @sql
from BooksTable ;

SET @sql = concat('SELECT  b.Name,
                           ', @sql, 
                  'FROM     Books b
                            INNER JOIN BooksTable bt
                                ON b.id = bt.Books
                    GROUP   BY  b.Name');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: The output is html, so a mysql pivot is unnecessary here. PHP can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_calc_books;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_calc_books (IN in_year INTEGER(4), OUT out_value       INTEGER(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
        SET @min_year = 0;

        SELECT MIN(year) INTO @min_year FROM bookstable;

        SELECT SUM(b.value) INTO out_value FROM books b
        JOIN bookstable bt ON bt.book = b.id
        WHERE bt.year BETWEEN @min_year AND  in_year;
COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can call it thru:

```
CALL sp_calc_books(2014, @output_var);
SELECT @output_var;
```